# Run "variable-build" command in Bash script

Tags: bash

I build a mysql command in a bash script. But in this script the mysql command does not work; the console shows the mysql default help output (as it was called with the "--help" argument). What is my mistake?

Here is the script:

```
declare mysql=/usr/bin/mysql
declare data=("ALTER TABLE ...", "ALTER TABLE ...")
declare args=""
declare dbName="testdb"

# In original version the following are received as parameter
declare live=true   
declare mysqlArgs="-u root"


for i in "${data[@]}"; do
     args="START TRANSACTION; $i;"

     if [ "$live" = true ] ; then
          cmd="$cmd COMMIT;"
      else
          cmd="$cmd ROLLBACK;" 
      fi

      cmd="-e '$cmd'"

      $mysql $mysqlArgs $cmd $dbName    # this does not work

      # if I copy the following output to console, it works fine
      echo "$mysql $mysqlArgs $cmd $dbName" 

done
```

The "echo" shows following:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u root -e 'START TRANSACTION; ALTER TABLE `test` DROP COLUMN `contactTypeId`;; ROLLBACK;' testdb
```

Comment: Where is `$mysql` declared or assigned?

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you paste the output from the echo which is working for you when pasted back into the console.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- search SO for this and you should find many near-duplicates.

Comment: The error seems in the -e parameter. So I changed to pipe the command:   echo $cmd | $mysqcmd ....